# python regex not matching as specified

Tags: python, regex

I have a piece of code as below:

```
 import re
 Regex1 = re.compile(r'([m-z]){3}')
 mo2 = Regex1.findall('mnodabcnopqr')
 print(mo2)
```

why it is printing 
    ['o', 'p']

and not matching 'mno', 'nop','pqr' ? I am a bit confused.

Comment: It is matching `mno`, but only the last `o` is stored in Group 1 that you defined with `(...)`. Remove `(` and `)`. To get overlapping matches  use `re.compile(r'(?=([m-z]{3}))')`

Comment: From re's `findall` documentation : `If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups`. Use `[m-z]{3}` if you want to avoid this behaviour as there's no reason to group a single token in order to quantify it.

Comment: I didn't understand one thing. I am using findall and you mentioned about group1. But when i try to print as print (mo2.group(0)), it gives

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'group'